# How can an <object> tag affect form submission

Tags: html, forms

Please provide an example of how to use the object tag in an HTML form.

I was reading the HTML5 spec today to learn what kind of form elements exist nowadays, and noticed the following:

> **Submittable elements**
>
> Denotes elements that can be used for constructing the form data set when a form element is submitted: button, input, keygen, object,
>   select, textarea
>   http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#category-submit

So apparently a form can have an object tag in it, affecting the data that is sent on form submission. The only context in which I was familiar with the object tag is to embed Flash movies onto a page. What would be an example situation where you could use the object tag in a form and have it affect the form submission data?

**Update:**

In the spec on how form payload is constructed on submit, found this interesting snippet in http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set

> If the field element is an object element: try to obtain a form
>   submission value from the plugin, and if that is successful, append an
>   entry to the form data set with name as the name, the returned form
>   submission value as the value, and the string "object" as the type.

But I wonder what kind of plugins hand out such submission values.

**Update:**

QtBrowserPlugin seems to support using them in forms. Now all I need for an example is a minimalistic such plugin.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/developingplugins.html#using-plugins-in-forms

Comment: Off topic, but an object is so much more than a Flash animation. It can pose as an `<applet>`, an `<iframe>`, an `<img>`... Even a `<xmp>` if you remember those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I suggest to use the latest HTML5 documentation at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set and not the HTML5.1 one.

I fear there's no browser that currently implement this behavior. In any case, if you want to *mimic* what the specification says to do, you can use a script like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.html" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myFieldID" name="myFieldName" value="Hello World!" />
    <object type="myPluginMIMETYPE" id="myPluginID" name="myPluginName" ></object>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( myForm ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        //Ask the plugin for some data, i.e. a flash object
        var pluginData = "pluginImportantData"; // ideally something like $(myPluginID).giveMeSomeDataBecauseUserWantsToSubmit();
        //Append the data before submission, giving to the input tag the right attributes
        $(this).append('<input type="object" name="myPluginName" value="'+ pluginData +'" style="visibility:hidden"/>');
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

On a second thought after trying it out it appears that putting a object tag inside of a form will not work, unless I may have missed a cretin tag that allows the object to be visible However you can use the div tag to separate objects. I have tried the following, the first section works fine, the section starting with "Form" does not show up in fire fox so it is possible that I missed something when writing it. EDIT= removed link (not helpful)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <object width="400" height="400" data="file name.***"></object>
    <div>
    <object width="500" height="500" data="file name.***"></object>

    <form>
    <object width="500" height="500" data="1r.txt">
    <object width="500" height="500" data="2r.txt">
    </object>
    </object>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should explain which part of that page you found helpful.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, but it seems your link doesn't talk about using object tags inside forms.

Comment: assuming that you are trying to separate objects or add links to objects